# How credible is it that a Mandalorian would befriend his target?

Tags: star-wars, the-mandalorian

I'm currently watching the Mandalorian TV show.

It is known that the Mandalorians have a [code of honor](https://starwars-exodus.fandom.com/wiki/Code_of_Honor). However, watching the show, I'm having an argument with some of my online mates regarding how credible it is that a Mandalorian warrior would go back to help one of his previous target.

My opinion is that the Mandalorian warrior has been influenced by the Force of the little Yoda-like creature (also known as the child).

Questions are the following:

- Have there been previous examples where Mandalorian warriors have rescued targets? (As far I can recall, Han Solo was not rescued by Fett therefore the answer would be no.)
- Is it a sound hypothesis that the Mandalorian warrior in the show has been "Force" influenced by the little Yoda-like creature?

Comment: There's no explicit evidence of The Child using the force to influence the protagonist. How far are you through the show? The protagonist is shown to have some history and character traits that explain why they have mercy for The Child, which in turn makes it less likely that he was being influenced by the Force.

Comment: Seems like you are conflating Mandalorian with Bounty Hunter's Guild.  There are different factions of Mandalorians with different beliefs about the Resol'nare.  Din Djarin is probably [Death Watch](https://www.cbr.com/star-wars-the-mandalorian-death-watch-explained/) who would obviously befiend his target because he did so. But by both Legends and Canon standards The Mandalorian is breaking [Bounty Hunter's Guild rules.](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Bounty_Hunters%27_Guild) They are two distinct ethos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Operating on a Mandalorian culture basis, being very honour bound as you say and leaving a child in custody of some people who mean to do them harm it's not very honourable.

They also do not like the Imperials after some apparent purge (not much detail given on that), as indicated by the adverse reaction to the Imperial Beskar. Giving an additional reason to one objecting to leaving a child with imperials.

The Mandalorians also have "foundlings" as a very important facet of their culture - someone who is not born as a Mandalorian, but is taken in and adopted into it.

This is said by the Armorer about them further emphasising their importance:

> "As it should always be. The Foundlings are the future."

And with the purge on their numbers, it's reasonable to say that makes it even more so.

The Mandalorian in the tv series also has personal background (which is later season), which gives an additional reasoning. Strikes a personal nerve.

In contrast, there's no evidence that the child is using any sort of force power to sway the Mandalorian. Especially as it's away from the child, that he makes the decision to go back.

As for previous records of Mandalorians going back to save a target: The closest equivalent I know of is in an [episode of Star Wars Rebels](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Blood_Sisters) with Sabine Wren and Ketsu Onyo. Both Mandalorians (and ones who prior knew each other) they clash over a bounty where Ketsu wants Sabine to hand over a droid named Chopper. Sabine refuses and as such becomes an active target, Ketsu trying to fire on her. But later both end up in a foul imperial situation forcing them to work together and Ketsu does end up eventually directly saving Sabine and abandoning the bounty. The two parting ways at the end of the episode.